# Reading Ubuntu installed magazines

Tags: ubuntu, documentation

I installed a digital edition of a magazine from the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center). But how do I read it?

Is there an accessory tool to access it?

Comment: How did you "installed a magazine"?

Comment: @Braiam I did from Ubuntu Software Center. It seems it just put a PDF copy in /opt/fullcircle/issues.
See the answers.

Comment: It's [these](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/trusty/books-magazines/) magazines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu Software Center offers lots of magazines and other publications, both paid and free, for download. Most of these should create an icon in your dash named after the magazine when downloaded. When you click the icon it should open the file browser to the location where the pdf files are stored. I just tried "installing" Full Circle Magazine and the pdf file was placed in `/opt/fullcircle/issues`.

Ubuntu comes with a very good PDF reader preinstalled (evince), so you should not have any trouble reading your magazine.